# How to run twilio programs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twilio

I am running this code which is giving error :

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

account_sid="AC9d3b9e6da765********************"
auth_token="5c6ff9b2e2dc********************"
client= TwilioRestClient(account_sid , auth_token)
message = client.sms.message.create(
    body="This is Deadshot",
    to="+919582******",
    from_="+91987*******")

print message.sid
```

on running it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\myFiles\twilio_demo.py", line 4, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twilio-6.3.0-py2.7.egg\twilio\rest\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from twilio.base.exceptions import TwilioException
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twilio-6.3.0-py2.7.egg\twilio\base\exceptions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from six import u
ImportError: No module named six
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pip install six
pip install requests
pip install pytz
```

and then run the code

try to upgrade the twillio to latest version and use the following code

```
    from twilio.rest import Client
    account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    auth_token  = "your_auth_token"

    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    message = client.messages.create(
        to="", 
        from_="",
        body="Hello from Python!")

print(message.sid)
```

Comment: where to write this ? @Exprator

Comment: in your terminal if you are using ubuntu/mac or cmd if you are using windows, and dont forget to add sudo at start if you use ubuntu/mac

Comment: now its giving an error in last line which says :                                          from requests import Request, Session
ImportError :  No module named requests .. @Exprator

Comment: any changes required in the original code ? @Exprator

Comment: no just install the libraries from you terminal, then run the program

Comment: Now I getting this error @Exprator Sir                                                                                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\myFiles\send_sms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
ImportError: cannot import name TwilioRestClient

Comment: which version of twilio are you using?

Comment: 6.3.0 @Exprator

Comment: now this error Sir @Exprator :   message = client.message.create(
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: it will be messages bro not message, why dont you copy my code and then paste it? then change your account and sid

Comment: import pytz
ImportError: No module named pytz

Comment: pip install pytz from your terminal